# MySQL Node not Access from Management Nodes in NDB Cluster

Tags: mysql

I am trying to deploy a 3 machine MySQL NDB Cluster with 1 Management Nodes on separate server, 1 SQL Nodes and 1 Data Nodes on same server. The base operating system is Ubuntu. I have access db from SQL Node and Data Node but cannot access from Management Node. I search about a long time and did not found any solution. anyone have idea about that.

Comment: Have you tried using root account?

Comment: yes i have tried using root but noting to access.@Justinas